# Can Adobe Portfolio be used to create embeddable HTML snippets?

Tags: html, adobe-lightroom, adobe-portfolio

I'd like to create galleries with Adobe Portfolio, which is included in my Photography plan. However, I maintain a Joomla site and would like to embed the galleries into it rather than creating a standalone site.

Can Portfolio be used as such, and will Lightroom publishing be available?